# How can i disconnect a socket both server and client side in socket.io 1.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Consider the following:

```
//client side: 
var socket = io('http://localhost');
//disconnecting client side 5 seconds after connecting
setTimeout(function(){
    socket.disconnect();
},5000);

//Server side:
var io = ......
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    setInterval(function(){
        console.log(socket.id);//this will continue outputting the socket.id forever.
    },1000);
});
```

Now my question is how will i disconnect from both server/client as the client approach alone doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your actual question: no need to do anything, the client is disconnected from the server. However the problem you're experiencing is not that the client is not disconnected, but that you have created an interval. In JavaScript a setInterval callback will continue to run **until you tell it to stop**.

Thus the solution is to tell it to stop when the client disconnects:

```
//Server side:
var io = ......
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
        console.log(socket.id); //this will continue outputting the socket.id until clearInterval() is called
    },1000);

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    });
});
```

Comment: then i explained my problem wrong. 1.) i know what intervals are i used interval just to demonstrate that socket.id is still valid even after disconnect.  2.) not needing to do anything .. it disconnect by its self .. well i dont know i mean `on("disconnect"` do fire but the socket is still alive .. so thats weird

Comment: Well that renders my answer useless for sure. But what do you mean with "the socket is still alive"? Even though the object still exists (which it always will since you have a reference to it) I'm pretty sure socket.io just doesn't send data into the void. After disconnect, `socket.connected = false`, `socket.disconnected = false` and the socket is not in `io.sockets.connected`. In what way is the socket not dead enough for you? Or rather: what problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: when i connect with 2 different browsers - i will have 2 `io.on("connection"` firing - which make sense, if i stop the app and immediately restart it after it will try to reconnect to those 2 sockets. now imaging the same situation only before restarting the server i disconnect one of the browsers, and then reset the server what you would expect happening is it will only reconnect to one socket but it reconnect them both..

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your reply. I just tried your scenario and to me it behaved as expected. Perhaps you should ask a question about that specific problem (with only the necessary code to reproduce it)?